# Get a file's icon or thumbnail

Tags: macos, cocoa

Is there a way, in OSX SDK, to represent a file in UI, by presenting its icon ?
In other words, is it possible to access the icon for a specific file, to show it in a NSImageView for example ?

PS: I'm using MonoMac, but Objective-C code will certainly help me too :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [NSWorkspace's iconForFile:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/iconForFile%3a)
e.g.:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFile:@"/Applications/Launchpad.app"];
```

If you need icons for a certain file type, you can use `iconForFileType:`

Answer (score 0):

I used this category
https://github.com/incbee/NSImage-QuickLook very helpful.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: If the path is an alias folder, this method returns an alias file icon: wrong.