# Does Cocoa provide a default way to make a visual icon for a file?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'm making a macOS app that is supposed to log data and return a file to the user. I would like to give the user a visual representation of the file that they can drag out and place where they want. It should work like a desktop, giving a visual thumbnail of the file. Does Cocoa provide a default way to do this? I know I've seen it done, especially in app install wizards: dragging the application into the Applications folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get a file's icon or thumbnail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16892668/get-a-files-icon-or-thumbnail)

Comment: @Willeke That returns an image, but I need an object that can be dragged by the user as a file.

Comment: That's another question. [Dragging files into other applications in cocoa OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40055527/dragging-files-into-other-applications-in-cocoa-osx),